# Joomla changing active menu

Tags: joomla, menu, components

How can the menu be changed using code?

I have found that:

```
$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
```

Returns the current active Menu item

However,

```
$menu->setActive( $menuitemid );
```

Does not do anything,

Whether I use,

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication(); $menu = $app->getMenu();
$menu->setActive( $menuitemid );
```

or,

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu(); $menu->setActive( $menuitemid );
```

How can I change the menu?

Comment: what do you mean by "is always shown on the Default menu"? Do you mean it shows when you click on a specific menu item such as "Home"? You can assign any component to any menu item.

Comment: I mean, it always gets rendered with the Default Menu,
As in, if you go to menu manager and select a menu
There is an option to make a menu default
And, this default menu always gets shown when my component is displayed
I want the active menu to be displayed, and not the default one